# $status=1 or 0 then display Enable or disable respected how can translate in yii2 MVC

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

My database column "status" stores "0 or 1" value but I want to display "Enable" or "disable"

[image]

Comment: problem is solved :) thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... This might be helpful to you.

Modify code as per your need.

```
  [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        if ($model->status == 0) {
            $status = 'disable';
        } elseif ($model->status == 1) {
            $status = 'Enable';
        } else {
            $status = 'Completed';
        }
        return $status;
    }
    ]
```

Comment: i want one more help yii2-jui not install  i can getting this error "yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found." so can you help me ??

Comment: Yes I have a solution for that also.. Please Ask A new question will give answer there.

And Please accept above answer if it was helpful to you.
Thanx.

Comment: that JUI issue is because of fxp/composer-asset-plugin

Comment: one more question about yii2 alredy post question in yii2 advanced

Comment: Didn't get your question bro.. Do you have query regarding  yii2 advanced.?

Comment: yes bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346499/how-multiple-row-delete-using-checkbox-in-yii2/37371524#37371524 this question