# how multiple row delete using checkbox in yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

How can I use in GridView delete selected object,in Yii 2 Framework such as following image:

[image]

[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?=Html::beginForm(['controller/bulk'],'post');?>
<?=Html::dropDownList('action','',[''=>'Mark selected as: ','c'=>'Confirmed','nc'=>'No Confirmed'],['class'=>'dropdown',])?>
<?=Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-info',]);?>
<?=GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => [
['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
'id',
],
]); ?>
<?= Html::endForm();?>
```

This is the controller:

```
public function actionBulk(){
    $action=Yii::$app->request->post('action');
    $selection=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection');//typecasting
    foreach($selection as $id){
        $e=Evento::findOne((int)$id);//make a typecasting
        //do your stuff
        $e->save();
    }
    }
```

Or Else

Follow all the steps given in this Link, You will Surely achive your goal.
[Yii 2 : how to bulk delete data in kartik grid view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397588/yii-2-how-to-bulk-delete-data-in-kartik-grid-view/)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397588/yii-2-how-to-bulk-delete-data-in-kartik-grid-view/
```

Comment: one issue is image not display :(  i ask one thing  yii2 advanced not give permission access image in Back-end  directory image direct ???

Comment: Use Web Directory to upload image.


$img = Url::to('@web/uploads/PROJECT/').$img_obj['AVATAR'];                 
$image = '<img src="'.$img.'" width="600" />';  


 <img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/backend/web/uploads/' . $model->profile_photo ?>" class=" img-responsive" >  
<?php echo Html::img('@web/img/icon.png', ['class' => 'pull-left img-responsive']); ?>

Comment: how multiple row delete using checkbox in yii2 this issue can not solved please help

Comment: what kind of issues are you facing ?? 
pls tell error message.

Comment: how multiple row delete using checkbox in yii2 ye issue solve ho gaya bro thanks @vijay bhai

Comment: Waah.. Great bhai enjoy :)

Comment: or more one question parent_id concept i can used  so i can bifergat sub category  for example ( "abc" is category  sub category "xyz"  i want sub category "abc->xyz"  ) any idea about that ???

Comment: Yes create a new question From Ask Question button i will explain theirabout your query.. Don't forget to tag me.. thanks

Comment: vijay bhai image not display    error ==> http://myshorter.tk/123/image%20issue.png

Comment: have you checked PAth and alias used ??

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/  that all yii2 aliases check every time same error but when put constant url that time work

Comment: vijay bhai aaj reply nahi kiya

Comment: Put you error. I am not getting axact issue.. Is it for image display in grid or some where else ??

Comment: woh sab ho gaya bhai sirf naya naya yii2 project pe kaam kar rahu isliye thoda sikhne me time lagta hey :P

Comment: You are learning very nicely. Keep it up dude. :)

Try to start learning How to use Extensions.. The Kartik Widgets nd grid are extremely good and very helpful to you.

Comment: nahi bhai codeigniter me work karna aacha lagta hey compare to yii2

Comment: yii-jui not installing its give error "yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found." how i can fix that ???

Comment: Ask new Question will give anser there

Comment: naya question post nahi kar pa raha hu grammer mistake ki error aa rahi hey

Comment: click on ask question button .

1) Write some description about issue first.

2 ) then put your error in question.

Comment: ab ja ke post huwa question

Answer (score 1):

You can use a column with checkboxes and bulk actions for each row selected.

Here is a related question:

[Yii2 How to properly create checkbox column in gridview for bulk actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992972/yii2-how-to-properly-create-checkbox-column-in-gridview-for-bulk-actions)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
<?php
$url = Url::to(['user/delete']);
$this->registerJs('
     $(document).on("click", "#delete_btn",function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
       var grid = $(this).data(\'grid\');
        var Ids = $(\'#\'+grid).yiiGridView(\'getSelectedRows\');
        var status = $(this).data(\'status\');
        if(Ids.length > 0){
        if(confirm("Are You Sure To Delete Selected Record !")){
              $.ajax({
                type: \'POST\',
                url :  \''.$url.'\' ,
                data : {ids: Ids},
                dataType : \'JSON\',
                success : function($resp) {
                if($resp.success){
                 alert(resp.msg);
                }
                }
            });
        }
        }else{
        alert(\'Please Select Record \');
}
    });
    ', \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
?>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFjT1.png
```

Comment: This is answer may work but vulnerable to csrf attack.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded in deleting multiple rows in gridview Yii2 by doing the following:

1. Create button in index.php

   `<p>
       <button type="button" onclick="getRows()" class="btn btn-success">Delete Bulk</button>
   </p>`
2. Add javascript code in index.php to perform the event of getting the checked rows from the GridView widget.

   `<script>
       function getRows() 
       {
           //var user_id as row_id from the gridview column
           // var list = [] is an array for storing the values selected from the //gridview 
           // so as to post to the controller.
           var user_id; 
            var list = []; 
   //input[name="selection[]"] this can be seen by inspecting the checkbox from your //gridview
           $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function(){
               user_id = this.value;
                list.push(user_id); 
           });
           $.ajax({
               type: 'post',
               url:'index.php?r=student-detail-update/bulk',
               data: {selection: list},
               });
           }
   </script>`
3. Put this code in your contoller

   `if ($selection=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection')) {
           foreach($selection as $id){
               $StudentDetailUpdates = StudentDetailUpdate::find()
               ->where(['user_id' => $id])
               ->all(); //....put your staff here
   }`